# Postfix - Force emails to stay in the queue for at least X seconds before sending

Tags: postfix

So I have been trying figure out how to modify Postfix email body messages without any real luck. I can figure out how to modify the first word but anything after that doesn't work.

So my second option is to do the following if it's possible.

1) Force all emails to be in the queue for at least 3 seconds

2) Bash a script every second to find and replace any text in `/var/spool/postfix` I don't want.

How can I do 1? `default_destination_rate_delay` would help but won't be ideal as there will be a few initial emails that get through without being modified.

Comment: see also here: http://serverfault.com/a/351846/2321

Answer (score 1):

The solution you propose would be a really, really fragile way to handle mail. Even if you manage to find a way to force Postfix to delay messages before processing them *and* find a way to make it re-read the queue files in order to pick up your modifications, I think you will encounter many other problems and reliability challenges with this approach. I really have to recommend that you do not try to do it.

I don't know what it is that you are doing that is somehow allowing you to modify the first word of the body but not anything else (sounds weird) but you should definitely persevere in your approach to hook into Postfix to modify the message body in a supported fashion.

A milter should be a straightforward way to modify a message body. Have you tried using or writing one of those? You can write milters in many different languages such as C and Python.

Remember that modifying message bodies in an MTA will lead to all sorts of problems such as invalidating PGP and DKIM signatures, etc...

Comment: Or just write an [after-queue content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).  Also, Postfix docs mention [altermime](http://www.pldaniels.com/altermime/) as a less broken (albeit not a bit less annoying to the end user) way of modifying messages' contents.